# CytoscapeJS remove node and shift edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

In CytoscapeJS, I'd like to remove a node (or "hide" a node) and then get the behavior that -- upon deleting that node -- I propagate edge relations. In other words, if I have `A -> B -> C`, and I delete `B`, I'd like to have `A -> C`, rather than `A` and `C` as distinct nodes with no edge between them. Is there a way to do this within Cytoscape? Or do I have to roll my own solution?

Comment: I am supposing that the easiest way would be to do something like `$("node").sources().addEdge($("node").target())` or something similar, yeah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this before B is removed:

```
var A = B.incomers().nodes()[0];
var C = B.outgoers().nodes()[0];

cy.add({
  data: { source: A.id(), target: C.id() } // ...
});
```

If B has more than 1 outgoer or more than 1 incomer, you'll need to loop.

Comment: This is really helpful. I'll mark it as accepted in a day or two when I implement this, and will comment on additional notes I find relevant.